# Can't login with session

Tags: .net, sql-server, session, authentication

I'm trying to login with session but there's something wrong. Its can't get values from the database to login. Please check the code and help me out.

Whenever I execute the code it won't go into the `if`. Database name is `Session` and table name is `login`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THIRD-I;Initial Catalog=Session;Integrated Security=True;");
    conn.Open();
    string query = "Select Count(*) From login Where user='" + txtuser.Text + "' and password='"+txtpass.Text+"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (output == "1")
    {
        Session["user"] = txtuser.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    }
    else
        Label3.Visible = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What r u getting in output variable

Comment: cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); returns the 1st row of the table in which i have "user" and "password"

Comment: At runtime what value you r getting in output variable

Comment: cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); returns the 1st row of the table in which i have "user" and "password".

Comment: In output variable i'm expecting the first row of the table "login"

Comment: You wont get the first row since you have written Count(*) in your query and executescalar also returns only a single value. Please debug and tell what are you getting in output variable.

Comment: Its showing null value

Comment: if you run the query in your SGBD (with the same user and password), what's the return? (Select Count(*) From login Where user='user_from_textbox' and password='passwor_from_textbox'). If you are getting null value, probably the query is wrong or there's no user and password in your table, or your dataset is pointing to wrong database. Try to confirm this points!

Comment: when i execute the query in SQL its returning 1 row but 0 value in it.
what should i do?

Comment: Thank you everyone. the problem was in the connection. when i write the query in **web.config** using `connectionStrings` the problem is solved.

Comment: Here is the Solved Code:

Comment: **Web.config**
`<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connect" connectionString="Data Source=THIRD-I;Initial Catalog=sessionlogin;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>`

Comment: **Login button**
`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());

conn.Open();
string query = "Select count(*) From logintable Where username='" + txtuser.Text + "' and password='"+txtpass.Text+"'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
if (output == "1"){
Session["user"] = txtuser.Text;
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
else Label3.Visible = true;`